How do I evaluate the relative and the absolute importance of the indicators of my formative construct in R (weights and loads)?
I have a formative construct named identity_motives that i created as a composite mean score of seven identity motives named innovatorlong_1 to innovatorlong_7 in my dataset named field_data.
This formative construct is a MODERATOR - it interacts with the independent variable ID13source_1 (a binary categorical variable with Internal Source and External Source as values) to predict ID13_profit (continuous variable).
I learnt that formative measurement models are evaluated based on the following: convergent validity, indicator collinearity, statistical significance, and relevance of the indicator weights.
I already estimated the convergent validity and the indicator collinearity. The seven formative indicators have VIF values ranging between 1.10 and 1.72, well below the commonly used threshold of 5, indicating no multicollinearity issues.
In the third and final step, I need to assess the indicator weights’ statistical significance and relevance (i.e. size). How do I do this in R?
I tried generating the code with ChatGPT but I am not sure whether and how I should specify the inner model. I am a beginner both with R and statistics.

Please spend more time reviewing [ask] and [MCVE]. This question is clearly not ready for SO prime time. It’s possible the someone will find it answerable at CrossValidated.com .
